# How do you convert a string into the name of an already created variable/list in python?

Tags: python

So basically here's a simplified version of my problem:

```
list1 = ["hi", "hello", "bye"]
list2 = ["x", "y", "z"]
variable = either "list1" or "list2"
```

And so I want to print the list that the value of the variable currently is but since it's a string, if you print it, it'll just print `"list1"` or `"list2"`. How could you print the correct list? Is there some function (I tried looking up one but I'm completely confused) that could convert it to a list name? Or some other way?

Comment: You could use `eval`/`exec`

Comment: Maintain a dictionary mapping from list name to list value e.g. `mapping = { "list1": list1, "list2": list2 }` then you can `print(mapping[variable])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three choices come into my mind:

1- grab it from your current scope(at the module level, `locals()` and `globals()` are the same dictionary)

```py
list1 = ["hi", "hello", "bye"]
print(locals()['list1'])
```

2- have a dictionary to map strings to the actual objects:

```py
list1 = ["hi", "hello", "bye"]
d = {'list1': list1}
print(d['list1'])
```

3- use `eval` (definitely not recommended when the input comes from somewhere else.)

```py
list1 = ["hi", "hello", "bye"]
print(eval("list1"))
```

I would go with **second** solution if you ask.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid `eval`. I believe in your case simple switch is ok:

```py
def return_list(name, list1, list2):
  if name == "list1":
    return list1
  if name == "list2":
    return list2
  return None

print(return_list("list1", list1, list2))
```

@jarmod's solution looks better, with small improvement:

```py
listmap = {
 "list1": list1,
 "list2": list2
}

variable = "list2"
value = None
if variable in listmap.keys():
  value = listmap[variable]

print(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to map from keys to values is to use a dictionary.

For example:

```
variable = "list1"

list1 = ["hi", "hello", "bye"]
list2 = ["x", "y", "z"]

mapping = { "list1": list1, "list2": list2 }
print(mapping[variable])
```